# XSLT ignore duplicate elements in single node at a time

Tags: xslt

I think my previous question was not clear so I am describing the situtation again.

Thanks for your help on this. I tried this but could not resolve my problem. I think I need to provide more insight into my issue.

```
    <TXLife>
        <TXLifeResponse>
            <Coverage>
                <LifeParticipant id="Party_040_01">
                    <ParticipantName>Sam</ParticipantName>
                    <LifeParticipantRoleCode tc="1">Primary Insured</LifeParticipantRoleCode>
                    <RateDecision>Rating C 100%</RateDecision>
                </LifeParticipant>
            </Coverage>
            <Coverage>
                <LifeParticipant id="Party_040_02">
                    <ParticipantName>Renny</ParticipantName>
                    <LifeParticipantRoleCode tc="2">Additional Insured</LifeParticipantRoleCode>
                    <RateDecision>Rating B 200%</RateDecision>
                </LifeParticipant>
            </Coverage>
            <Coverage>
                <LifeParticipant id="Party_040_01">
                    <ParticipantName>Sam</ParticipantName>
                    <LifeParticipantRoleCode tc="1">Primary Insured</LifeParticipantRoleCode>
                    <RateDecision>Rating D 700%</RateDecision>
                </LifeParticipant>
            </Coverage>
        </TXLifeResponse>
        <TXLifeResponse>
            <Coverage>
                <LifeParticipant id="Party_040_01">
                    <ParticipantName>Marry</ParticipantName>
                    <LifeParticipantRoleCode tc="1">Primary Insured</LifeParticipantRoleCode>
                    <RateDecision>Rating C 100%</RateDecision>
                </LifeParticipant>
            </Coverage>
            <Coverage>
                <LifeParticipant id="Party_040_03">
                    <ParticipantName>Sherry</ParticipantName>
                    <LifeParticipantRoleCode tc="2">Primary Insured</LifeParticipantRoleCode>
                    <RateDecision>Rating H 300%</RateDecision>
                </LifeParticipant>
            </Coverage>
            <Coverage>
                <LifeParticipant id="Party_040_01">
                    <ParticipantName>Marry</ParticipantName>
                    <LifeParticipantRoleCode tc="1">Primary Insured</LifeParticipantRoleCode>
                    <RateDecision>Rating A 50%</RateDecision>
                </LifeParticipant>
            </Coverage>
        </TXLifeResponse>
    </TXLife>
```

I need to find the RateDecision information by LifeParticipantRoleCode from multiple Coverage elements within TXLifeResponse at a time. And repeat the same for second TXLifeResponse and so on.

```
    Meaning I need to generate output like

    <TXLife>
        <TXLifeResponse>
            <RateDecision>Sam Rating C 100%, Rating D 700%</RateDecision>
            <RateDecision>Renny Rating B 200%</RateDecision>
        </TXLifeResponse>
        <TXLifeResponse>
            <RateDecision>Marry Rating C 100%, Rating A 50%</RateDecision>
            <RateDecision>Sherry Rating H 300%</RateDecision>
        </TXLifeResponse>
    </TXLife>
```

I don't want to generate two  elements for Sam. I want to combine Sam's rating information from two different Coverage elements under single TXLifeResponse node and display it and then repeat the same process for second TXLifeResponse node.

I hope, I am able to clarify my question. Any help is appreciated.

I tried to implement the below logic and its still not working. Please assist.

```
<xsl:key name="LifeParticipant-by-LifeParticipantRoleCode" match="LifeParticipant" use="LifeParticipantRoleCode[@tc = '1' or @tc = '2' or @tc = '3' or @tc = '4' or @tc = '5' or @tc = '6']" />

<xsl:apply-templates select="Life/Coverage/LifeParticipant[generate-id() = generate-id(key('LifeParticipant-by-LifeParticipantRoleCode', LifeParticipantRoleCode/@tc)[1])]" />

<xsl:template match="LifeParticipant">
    <!-- Business Logic -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: And what is your desired result and what is not working?

Comment: The above XSLT is ignoring the duplicate LifeParticipant/@id across the TXLifeResponse nodes. I want  it to ignore LifeParticipant/@id only within the current TXLifeResponse node and apply the same for second TXLifeResponse node an so on.

Comment: "*I tried this but could not resolve my problem.*" Post your attempt. -- P.S. Don't use the word "urgent". Everyone here donates their time and you have no right to rush anyone.

Comment: My apologies. I don't mean to rush anybody for my help. Just stuck around for this for couple of days and not getting any breakthrough. I have taken out the word "urgent" from my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing duplicates (in XSLT 1.0) is best handled through a technique known as [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

The variation required here is to include the id of the parent node in the key. Here's an example of implementation:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k" match="Coverage" use="concat(LifeParticipant/@id, '|', generate-id(..))"/>

<xsl:template match="/TXLife">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="TXLifeResponse"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TXLifeResponse">
    <group>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Coverage[count(. | key('k', concat(LifeParticipant/@id, '|', generate-id(..)))[1]) = 1]"/>
    </group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Coverage">
    <item>
        <xsl:value-of select="LifeParticipant"/>
    </item>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the given example input, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <group>
      <item>tom</item>
      <item>sam</item>
   </group>
   <group>
      <item>tom</item>
      <item>jerry</item>
   </group>
</root>
```

I didn't see anything concerning "multiple files" here.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this but I could not resolve my issue using this. I have updated my original question to provide more insight into my problem domain. Please review my original question and provide your help on this.

Comment: My answer stands. The principle is the same, the differences are minute. Please make your own adjustments.

Comment: sorry for late update on this. I was able to resolve the issue using your solution (Muenchian grouping). Appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a environment that could test this so only sudo code and not 100% sure it will work but what I would attempt with an issue like this is

```
Template Match at TXLifeResponse level
   for each coverage/LifeParticipant
     xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::LifeParticipant[@id=current()/@id])
       set variable (paramContext) to be current()    
       xslt:value-of setting value using a call to custom function (func1) passing paramContext, @id  and an empty string 
     end if
   end loop
end template
```

Then the function would use recursion something like the below

```
 if test="(paramContext/following-sibling::LifeParticipant[@id=paramID])
    set variable newContext = paramContext/following-sibling::LifeParticipant[@id=paramID]
    set variable concatstring = paramString concatenated with delimiter and RateDecision
    call func1 (recursivly) passing NewContext, paramID, concatString
  end if
end loop
```

Not sure if the context stuff will work but need to do something here otherwise the function will change the context in the outer section.

Comment: Hi Shaun,  I tried this but its does not seem to work.

Comment: @user2324686 Updated answer to match your revised / clarified requirements.