# How to restrict key() to search within a child node and not entire xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there any way in XSLT 1.0 to restrict the function key() to search within a child node and not entire input XML.
My input XML is

```
    <a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d name="1"/>
            <d name="2"/>
            <d name="3"/>
            <d name="1"/>
        </c>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d name="1"/>
            <d name="2"/>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

XSLT that I have written is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="findD" match="d" use="@name"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <start>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="a/b/c"/>
    </start>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a/b/c">
    <inside>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('findD', '1')">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </inside>
</xsl:template>
```

Which results in

```
    <?xml version='1.0' ?>
<start>
    <inside>
        <d name="1"/>
        <d name="1"/>
        <d name="1"/>
    </inside>
    <inside>
        <d name="1"/>
        <d name="1"/>
        <d name="1"/>
    </inside>
</start>
```

What I need is something like

```
     <?xml version='1.0' ?>
<start>
    <inside>
        <d name="1"/>
        <d name="1"/>
    </inside>
    <inside>
        <d name="1"/>
    </inside>
</start>
```

This returns all the three nodes 'd' (present in xml) for every c node. While what I need is to get d nodes within corresponding c node (when key is called).

I have seen use of concat within key() where one can concat result based on node c's value. Is there any other way to say key() to look within a node only and not entire XML.

Comment: Oops, a copy paste error in my example XSLT. Use of key function is ------ <xsl:key name="findD" match="d" use="@name"/> -------- and ------   <xsl:for-each select="key('findD', '1')">-----------

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: I cannot figure out what you're trying to do. In general, to restrict the key to the parent node, concatenate the value with the id of the parent node - see an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793795/xslt-ignore-duplicate-elements-in-single-node-at-a-time/33796222#33796222

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. I have edited my question now. I am looking for any alternative other than concatenate (since my real problem) is much more complex and will end up concatenating too many values.

Comment: I don't know of another way (in XSLT 1.0) and I still don't understand your example. And I believe you only need to concatenate two values - the actual key value and the id of the parent (or ancestor) node in which you want the key to operate.

Comment: @DJ1 - I think you may need to edit your question to make it more representative of the problem you are trying to solve. At the moment, the way the question is currently posed, instead of doing `<xsl:for-each select="key('findD', '1')">`, you can just do `<xsl:for-each select="d[@name='1']">`, which is possibly not what you want in your actual case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer:

```
<xsl:key name="findD" match="d" use="generate-id(..)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <start>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a/b/c"/>
  </start>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a/b/c">
  <xsl:variable name="parentID" select="generate-id(.)"/>
  <inside>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('findD', $parentID)[@name='1']">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </inside>
</xsl:template>
```

Please tell us why you want to use a key here.  Just using normal push programming would be a very efficient and straight forward way to solve this problem.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <start>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a/b/c"/>
  </start>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c">
  <inside>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="d[@name='1']"/>
  </inside>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="d">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```