# In my xslt file I used a key and it only works the first time it's used

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am using a key to find a unique list of elements.
It works fine the first time it gets called but does not on subsequent calls.
I'm new to xslt so any help is appreciated!

Here is my xsl file contents:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

  <!-- Global Parameters -->
  <xsl:param name="POSLINK" select="'Y'"/>

  <!-- Set output method to indicate a text file (not XML) -->
  <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="text" media-type="plain/text"/>

  <!-- NAXML-MovementReport template -->
  <xsl:template match="NAXML-MovementReport">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="FuelGradeMovement/FGMDetail"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Key for unique LoyaltyName -->
  <xsl:key name="nameDistinct" match="Extension/LoyaltyDiscounts/LoyaltyDiscount" use="LoyaltyName"/>

  <xsl:template match="FGMDetail">
    <xsl:if test="$POSLINK='Y'">
      <xsl:variable name="fuelGradeIDs" select="FuelGradeID"/>
      <xsl:if test="count($fuelGradeIDs)=1">
        <xsl:variable name="fuelGradeID" select="string($fuelGradeIDs[1])"/>
        <xsl:if test="$fuelGradeID != ''">
          <!-- stops on the line below after first time -->
          <xsl:for-each select="Extension/LoyaltyDiscounts/LoyaltyDiscount[generate-id() = generate-id(key('nameDistinct', LoyaltyName)[1])]">
            <xsl:variable name="loyaltyName" select="string(LoyaltyName)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="vAllowedSymbols" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
            <xsl:variable name="fixedName" select="normalize-space(translate($loyaltyName, translate($loyaltyName, $vAllowedSymbols, ' '), ' '))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="amounts" select="../LoyaltyDiscount[LoyaltyName=$loyaltyName]/DiscountAmount"/>
            <xsl:variable name="total" select="round(sum(../LoyaltyDiscount[LoyaltyName=$loyaltyName]/DiscountAmount) * 100) div 100"/>
            <xsl:text>"DID",0,,"DTot-LoyDiscByFuelProdAmt-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$fixedName"/>
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$fuelGradeID"/>
            <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$total"/>
            <xsl:text>,,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<NAXML-MovementReport version="3.4">
    <TransmissionHeader>
        <StoreLocationID>2</StoreLocationID>
        <VendorName>Gilbarco-VeederRoot</VendorName>
        <VendorModelVersion>21.03.26.01</VendorModelVersion>
    </TransmissionHeader>
    <FuelGradeMovement>
        <MovementHeader>
            <ReportSequenceNumber>1</ReportSequenceNumber>
            <PrimaryReportPeriod>2</PrimaryReportPeriod>
            <SecondaryReportPeriod>0</SecondaryReportPeriod>
            <BusinessDate>2023-05-11</BusinessDate>
            <BeginDate>2023-05-11</BeginDate>
            <BeginTime>23:45:39</BeginTime>
            <EndDate>2023-05-12</EndDate>
            <EndTime>23:45:47</EndTime>
        </MovementHeader>
        <FGMDetail>
            <FuelGradeID>096</FuelGradeID>
            <Extension>
                <LoyaltyDiscounts>
                    <LoyaltyDiscount>
                        <LoyaltyName>Chevron &amp; Safeway</LoyaltyName>
                        <DiscountAmount>4.44</DiscountAmount>
                    </LoyaltyDiscount>
                    <LoyaltyDiscount>
                        <LoyaltyName>PM Loyalty</LoyaltyName>
                        <DiscountAmount>0.6</DiscountAmount>
                    </LoyaltyDiscount>
                </LoyaltyDiscounts>
                    <LoyaltyDiscount>
                        <LoyaltyName>Chevron &amp; Safeway</LoyaltyName>
                        <DiscountAmount>10.00</DiscountAmount>
                    </LoyaltyDiscount>
            </Extension>
        </FGMDetail>
        <FGMDetail>
            <FuelGradeID>001</FuelGradeID>
            <Extension>
                <LoyaltyDiscounts>
                    <LoyaltyDiscount>
                        <LoyaltyName>Chevron &amp; Safeway</LoyaltyName>
                        <DiscountAmount>123.8</DiscountAmount>
                    </LoyaltyDiscount>
                    <LoyaltyDiscount>
                        <LoyaltyName>PM Loyalty</LoyaltyName>
                        <DiscountAmount>0.42</DiscountAmount>
                    </LoyaltyDiscount>
                </LoyaltyDiscounts>
            </Extension>
        </FGMDetail>
        <FGMDetail>
            <FuelGradeID>003</FuelGradeID>
            <Extension>
                <LoyaltyDiscounts>
                    <LoyaltyDiscount>
                        <LoyaltyName>Chevron &amp; Safeway</LoyaltyName>
                        <DiscountAmount>38.32</DiscountAmount>
                    </LoyaltyDiscount>
                    <LoyaltyDiscount>
                        <LoyaltyName>PM Loyalty</LoyaltyName>
                        <DiscountAmount>0.07</DiscountAmount>
                    </LoyaltyDiscount>
                </LoyaltyDiscounts>
            </Extension>
        </FGMDetail>
        <FGMDetail>
            <FuelGradeID>019</FuelGradeID>
            <Extension>
                <LoyaltyDiscounts>
                    <LoyaltyDiscount>
                        <LoyaltyName>Chevron &amp; Safeway</LoyaltyName>
                        <DiscountAmount>12.63</DiscountAmount>
                    </LoyaltyDiscount>
                </LoyaltyDiscounts>
            </Extension>
        </FGMDetail>
    </FuelGradeMovement>
</NAXML-MovementReport>
```

The goal of this is to create a text file with unique records containing the FuelGradeID, the LoyaltyName (no special chars) and the sum of the DiscountAmount elements. If you run the example you should get the output of the first record. I need it to continue to do this for all the FGMDetail elements.

Desired Output:

```
"DID",0,,"DTot-LoyDiscByFuelProdAmt-Chevron Safeway-096",14.44,,
"DID",0,,"DTot-LoyDiscByFuelProdAmt-PM Loyalty-096",0.6,,
"DID",0,,"DTot-LoyDiscByFuelProdAmt-Chevron Safeway-096",123.8,,
"DID",0,,"DTot-LoyDiscByFuelProdAmt-PM Loyalty-096",0.42
"DID",0,,"DTot-LoyDiscByFuelProdAmt-Chevron Safeway-096",38.32,,
"DID",0,,"DTot-LoyDiscByFuelProdAmt-PM Loyalty-096",0.07,,
"DID",0,,"DTot-LoyDiscByFuelProdAmt-Chevron Safeway-096",12.63,,
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question to detail exactly what you're trying to do and add an example of the desired output? That way we don't have to try to determine what you're trying to do based on code that doesn't work.

Comment: I updated my question. I just need it to do the same thing it did for the first FGMDetail element to the other FGMDetail elements and output records like those shown. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is still not clear. I am guessing (!) this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33796222/3016153. If not, please reduce the code examples to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem and add the **exact** result you expect to get.

Comment: I guess my question is, can you use the key I defined above more than once? Why does it work on the first FGMDetail element and not the others? CAN I do this or is a key just a one time thing? Do I need to find yet another way to simply group like records and sum them (this is like the 10th attempt)? It would be astonishingly simple in a real language to group records together. It looks like there is a group-by in version 2 but that's not what my employer uses. I can't see why anyone would use this over C# Xml Documents but it's not my call.

Comment: Your rant does not help to clarify your question.

Comment: My question is, can you use the key I defined above more than once? Why does it work on the first FGMDetail element and not the others? CAN I do this or is a key just a one time thing? I can't make the xslt much simpler other than removing the couple of lines that remove special characters.
1. group records by FuelGradeID, LoyaltyName
2. sum the DiscountAmount of grouped records
3. create 1 record for each group of FuelGradeID, LoyaltyName & sum(DiscountAmount) formatted as it is in the result code above. (I'll add the rest)

Comment: Perhaps it is unclear that, when I use FuelGradeMovement/FGMDetail in the template call, the template is called for each FGMDetail element. The code above only works the first time the template is called.

Comment: Why is your expected result for "Chevron Safeway-096" `4.44` and not `14.44`?

Comment: It should be 14.44. Sorry, I switched my test data. It does come out to 14.44 if you run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key in XSLT 1.0 works across the entire XML document. In order to group `LoyaltyDiscount` elements only within their `FGMDetail` branch, you must include a unique identifier of the branch in the key's definition and in the call to the key function.

Here is a **simplified** example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:key name="k1" match="LoyaltyDiscount" use="concat(LoyaltyName, '|', generate-id(ancestor::FGMDetail))"/>

<xsl:template match="/NAXML-MovementReport">
    <xsl:for-each select="FuelGradeMovement/FGMDetail">
        <xsl:variable name="fuelGradeID" select="FuelGradeID" />
        <!-- a row for each distinct LoyaltyDiscount in this FGMDetail -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Extension/LoyaltyDiscounts/LoyaltyDiscount[count(. | key('k1', concat(LoyaltyName, '|', generate-id(ancestor::FGMDetail)))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="$fuelGradeID" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="LoyaltyName" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <!-- sum of current group -->
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('k1', concat(LoyaltyName, '|', generate-id(ancestor::FGMDetail)))/DiscountAmount)" />
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will return:

**Result**

```
096,Chevron & Safeway,14.44
096,PM Loyalty,0.6
001,Chevron & Safeway,123.8
001,PM Loyalty,0.42
003,Chevron & Safeway,38.32
003,PM Loyalty,0.07
019,Chevron & Safeway,12.63
```

Make your own adjustments for the parts unrelated to the issue. Note that with some processors you may have to round or format the sum to avoid floating-point round-off errors.

Comment: You rock! Thank you! I really appreciate your help! Sorry about the rant, just frustrated with an unfamiliar language =).

Comment: Yeah, it takes some getting used to.