# XSLT to remove inner duplicates and normalize unique values

Tags: xslt-1.0

I would like to achieve the following requirement via xslt 1.0 transformation.
Assume to have this XML:

```
<download>
    <transport>
        <complex_structure_nested_1/>
        <statuses last_status_code="20">
            <status>
                <code>20</code>
                <description>Code Description</description>
            </status>
            <status>
                <code>20</code>
                <description>Code Description</description>
            </status>
            <status>
                <code>10</code>
                <description>Code Description</description>
            </status>
        </statuses>
    </transport>
    <transport>
        <complex_structure_nested_2/>
        <statuses last_status_code="30">
            <status>
                <code>30</code>
                <description>Code Description</description>
            </status>
            <status>
                <code>20</code>
                <description>Code Description</description>
            </status>
            <status>
                <code>20</code>
                <description>Code Description</description>
            </status>
    </transport>
</download>
```

I would need to remove code duplicates and generate transports carrying single statuses.
Inside each instance x of transport there is a complex structure named complex_structure_nested_x

```
<download>
    <transport>
        <complex_structure_nested_1/>
        <statuses last_status_code="20">
            <status>
                <code>20</code>
                <description>Code Description</description>
            </status>
        </statuses>
    </transport>
    <transport>
        <complex_structure_nested_1/>
        <statuses last_status_code="20">
            <status>
                <code>10</code>
                <description>Code Description</description>
            </status>
        </statuses>
    </transport>
    <transport>
        <complex_structure_nested_2/>
        <statuses last_status_code="30">
            <status>
                <code>30</code>
                <description>Code Description</description>
            </status>
        </statuses>
    </transport>
    <transport>
        <complex_structure_nested_2/>
        <statuses last_status_code="30">
            <status>
                <code>20</code>
                <description>Code Description</description>
            </status>
        </statuses>
    </transport>
</download>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Here is an example you could use as your starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76336354/in-my-xslt-file-i-used-a-key-and-it-only-works-the-first-time-its-used/76341386#76341386